# Amazon affiliate - Is there a way to track the purchase & order details of a product from my website?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, affiliate

I had my website developed with HTML5 & Javascript and I am being an affiliate to Amazon and advertising amazon products on my website.

Now my question is:

When a user redirects to Amazon from my website and purchases a product, can we get the order/purchase id of that particular purchase and can we track it's status and show it in my website.